# Is PlayN on iOS possible without licensing MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, playn

Following the [instructions on the PlayN wiki](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/iOSBuild) I was able to get the "hello" PlayN sample running on the iOS simulator. However, when using MonoStudio, I was told that I need to upgrade to an [Indie license or higher](https://store.xamarin.com/) to compile the code. (Apparently I was using 33+ features which required it.) When I activated a trial edition, the sample compiled and ran fine on the simulator.

The PlayN wiki seems to indicate the you'd only need a license if you plan on testing on a real device. Is it wrong or am I missing something?

Also, I thought the idea behind PlayN was to build a free, open source game engine on top of free, open-source technology. Mono is both, but MonoTouch is neither. Is there another option or am I stuck with shelling out $1000/year to use iOS (which so far seems far from fully implemented on the PlayN side of things)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, there isn't. Sorry its disappointing, but its the nature of iOS. Its a very non-free platform.

Perhaps you can try your hands at writing a cross compiler, and release it under an opensource license? You can try basing it on http://gcc.gnu.org/java/.

Comment: Well my theory right now is j2objc is PlayN's best bet, with a Platform written in Objective-C rather than Java as it is now. I'm going to try my hand and see how it goes. Thanks for confirming my unhappy suspicions.

Comment: ah didnt know about j2objc - sounds promising.

Comment: @thomas88wp did you ever try it w/ j2objc?  That was my instinctual response to this; it has pretty solid support for all sorts of java, even reflection I was told (I met the author at a conference he presented at, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwhfyQG3myc ).  It just generates some very verbose objC which you can plug in to any native bits you might need.

Comment: I did get most of the way, a while ago. You can see the code here: https://github.com/thomaswp/playn-ios. Essentially I got the demo games to run, but there was a lot I didn't cover. Unfortunately, the PlayN developers have changed a lot since then, so I don't know how useful it would be with the 2.0 API.